Must electronic funds transfers in the US be completed within some maximum amount of time defined by law?
I am moving some money between 2 US banks via ACH (Automated Clearing House) and it's taking almost 1 week ("Hold Placed on Electronic Deposit added"). This makes me wonder: since US banks are allowed to invest money that is currently being transferred via electronic funds transfer, must electronic funds transfers in the US be completed within some maximum amount of time defined by law? E.g., o take an extreme example, can a US bank take 1 year to complete the transfer and pocket all the return on investment made using that money?

Hold is different from "completed". Hold is a security measure after the money has been transferred and posted on your account. There are rules on holds, we had a question on that on the Money@SE stack.

Read your contract
The terms of service you agreed to should spell this out. Almost certainly, the bank is not going to be responsible for things beyond its control.

I think the question refers to regulation CC
